# About net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID Error while making Board with Spring Framework

Tags: spring

I'm trying to make board with Spring Framework(javascript) and

other people uses $ tags to make functions while I cannot use those methods

due to net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID ERROR.

I cannot find any solution for solve this problem...

can anyone give me a hint or way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

this code produces net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID ERROR.

so the alternative solution I used to solve this was using this code,

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you cannot load resources from jquery script,try to use the above code instead of first code I used.